# Pip is not installing in Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, hosting

Heroku Pip install error.

```
remote:        Collecting multidict==4.7.6
remote:          Downloading multidict-4.7.6-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (148 kB)
remote:        ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip==20.2.220.2.2 (from -r /tmp/build_74e933be/requirements.txt (line 8)) (from versions: 0.2, 0.2.1, 0.3, 0.3.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5.1, 0.6, 0.6.1, 0.6.2, 0.6.3, 0.7, 0.7.1, 0.7.2, 0.8, 0.8.1, 0.8.2, 0.8.3, 1.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.1, 1.2, 1.2.1, 1.3, 1.3.1, 1.4, 1.4.1, 1.5, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.4, 1.5.5, 1.5.6, 6.0, 6.0.1, 6.0.2, 6.0.3, 6.0.4, 6.0.5, 6.0.6, 6.0.7, 6.0.8, 6.1.0, 6.1.1, 7.0.0, 7.0.1, 7.0.2, 7.0.3, 7.1.0, 7.1.1, 7.1.2, 8.0.0, 8.0.1, 8.0.2, 8.0.3, 8.1.0, 8.1.1, 8.1.2, 9.0.0, 9.0.1, 9.0.2, 9.0.3, 10.0.0b1, 10.0.0b2, 10.0.0, 10.0.1, 18.0, 18.1, 19.0, 19.0.1, 19.0.2, 19.0.3, 19.1, 19.1.1, 19.2, 19.2.1, 19.2.2, 19.2.3, 19.3, 19.3.1, 20.0, 20.0.1, 20.0.2, 20.1b1, 20.1, 20.1.1, 20.2b1, 20.2, 20.2.1, 20.2.2)
remote:        ERROR: No matching distribution found for pip==20.2.220.2.2 (from -r /tmp/build_74e933be/requirements.txt (line 8))
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
```

Answer (score 0):

It can not find the version `pip==20.2.220.2.2` as it says on the error.

You should choose a proper version like `pip==20.2.2`.